# Unable to import dart library for command line app

Tags: import, dart, dart-editor

When initiating a command line utility in dart, I get the following directory structure:

```
happy/
  bin/
    main.dart
  lib/
    happy.dart
    user.dart
```

Where happy.dart, and user.dart are identical except for their containing libraries: happy, and user respectively.

in happy.dart:

```dart
library happy; // user in user.dart

int calculate() {
  return 6 * 7;
}
```

in main.dart I have:

```dart
import 'package:happy/happy.dart'; // changing to user underlines this in red

main() {
  print('Hello world: ${happy.calculate()}!');
}
```

Which works, but when the user library is used instead of happy, the import fails.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should definitely work if you change it to `import 'package:happy/user.dart';`

Comment: Did you use `'package:user/user. dart'` instead? The first `user` is the package name but your package is named `happy`.

Comment: I tried changing the package name in user.dart to `user`. That seemed not to work. I guess that is the way it is supposed to be.

Comment: You can't change the package name in `user.dart` the package name is defined in `pubspec.yaml`. If you change the package name you need to run `pub get` or `pub upgrade`.